# create a surface from 5 points

Tags: mesh

[image: Please Help With This Image]

I have a model, and I accidentally deleted some vertices, and I need to get the surface back. The hole is outlined in red in this image. I have 5 vertices and have no idea how to make the surface.

Comment: Select 3 vertices and click F to fill, and so on (as it looks like you work with tris)

Answer (score 4):

Since your mesh is triangulated, you should create three triangle faces. For instance you could connect them in the following pattern.

[image: Topology]

In order to accomplish this, switch into *Edit Mode* (<kbd>TAB</kbd>) and enable *Vertex Select*.

[image: Vertex select]

Select the three vertices (and only the three vertices) that are supposed to form a face. Once they are selected press <kbd>F</kbd> to create the face. Deselect the vertices (<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>) and repeat with the next three vertices.